# How to set the non duplicate selected value in dropdownlist

Tags: jquery

I have a table with multiple rows. Each row has a dropdownlist. The user cannot select two same options from a dropdownlist in each row. Meaning if the user selects option A from the dropdownlist in row 1 he/she cannot selected Option A from the dropdownlist in row 2 or 3 or any other row.

I simply select the first item in the list but of course this will not work:

```
function isSelectedOptionValid(selectedOption) {

    var isValid = true; 
    var rows = $(selectedOption).parent().parent().siblings(".TBLCONTENTS");
    var tds = rows.find("td");

    for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {

        var option = $($($(rows[i]).find("td")[1]).find("select")[0]).val();

        if (option == $(selectedOption).val()) {

            // find the option that is not selected 
            $(selectedOption).children(":first").attr("selected", "selected");

            isValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isValid;

}
```

Comment: you want to remove the option ? how are you going to stop the user selecting the option ?

Comment: Whenever user selects one item, push it in array and when user selects another item, check whether it's present in array or not. If it's present that mean that item has been selected in other list.
You can set up indexes according to your dropdown list number.From each list only one element can be pushed in array.

Comment: I just want to select an option that the user has not selected.

Comment: As I said, user selected item will be present in array and when he selects another item let it be from some other list also, it's not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-

```
 $(function() { 
    var a=new Array();
    $(".list").each(function(){
    $(this).change(function(){
        if(a[$(this).index]!=$(this).val()){
            a[$(this).index]=$(this).val();
        }else{
            alert('Already There');             
        }
    });
 });
});
```

and HTML for this-

```
 <select class="list">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 </select>
 <select class="list">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 </select>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aHdtr/)